# Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified - codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

my model file name is **`M_zwall.php` :**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_zwall extends CI_Model {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
  }


    public function getLastWallpapers($start = 0,$end = 0)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('wallpapers');
        $this->db->limit(10,$start);
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }


   }
?>
```

I loaded this model in my **controller :**

```
$this->load->model('m_zwall');
```

but I got this **error :**

> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: M_zwall

**updated**

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_zwall');


}
```

Comment: Which version of CI you use??

Comment: where did you load model in controller ??

Comment: @Stay `CodeIgniter 3.1.0`

Comment: Which folder you were stored your Model?
if its inside models folder no problem. In case under models/folder_name
you have to call it by name $this->load->model(array('folder_name/M_zwall'));

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Try with out using `?>` at bottom of page.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Sounds like your file, `M_zwall.php` is not placed in `/application/models/` folder.

Comment: make file name in lowercase and den load it i.e. m_zwall.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
$this->load->model('M_zwall');
```

Comment: That should not really make much difference would think

Answer (score 0):

Try to change file name M_zwall.php to m_zwall.php